# How to programatically dismiss a message dialogue after a certain process has ended - Java

Tags: java, swing

How could I show a `JOptionPane` at the beginning of a certain function, by having for example, "Working...",  and then programmatically dismiss it at the end of said function/piece of code?

Comment: That's basically why [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) was created.

Comment: You could add `JOptionPane.dispose()` at the end of the task. End of the task means last code statement for the task. Won't be able to help much since you haven't provided any code. You may want to read about `Event Dispatch Thread` before getting on with it.

Comment: @MathewsMathai a JOptionPane doesn't have a dispose() method

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Not regular at Java GUI. This---> `JOptionPane.getRootFrame().dispose();` or use `setVisible()` like Dalton suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your queston, you can run this piece of code:

```
//Declare the JOptionPane object
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();

function yourFunction(){
     //Beginning
     pane.showInternalMessageDialog(frame, "Working...", "information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

     //End
     pane.setVisible(false); //or pane.dispose();
}
```

The code can be enhanced by calling the pane.dispose() method when hiding the pane to release the system resources used by the pane.

Comment: Thanks, but with this code the OptionPane keeps the execution from proceeding until I press the "Ok" button. Is there a way to remove it so that the dialog doesn't lock the execution?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a `JOptionPane` pops up it do so in a different thread so you can do it as mentioned below:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
    private JOptionPane pane;
    private JDialog dialog;
    private Timer t;

    public Main()
    {
        t = new Timer(2000, closeJDialog);
        t.start();

        pane = new JOptionPane("My Dialog Message to You!");
        dialog = pane.createDialog("My Dialog Title");
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ActionListener closeJDialog = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                int i = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

                // Call your function here

                dialog.dispose();
                System.out.println("dialog disposed");
            }
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                new Main();
            }
        });
    }
}
```